# Changing color of inner element in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, combobox, styles

I have a template for Combobox, code is mostly from [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx).
I want to change the color of the arrow to gray, when the combo box is disabled.
any ideas?

here's the code:

```
<!--ComboBoxStyle-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AlpmGray}" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="0" Margin="1" Background="White"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ComboPath}"/>
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource AlpmRed}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox"
             TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"  Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2"
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Style="{x:Null}"
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             Margin="3,3,23,3"
                             Focusable="True"
                             Background="Transparent"
                             Visibility="Hidden"
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                                                           MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AlpmColorLightGray}" />
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="White">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AlpmColorLightGray}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AlpmColorLightGray}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: What about using a `Trigger` to change the color when `Enabled` is `False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to bind the Fill on the shape to the foreground of the toggle button, which you can either do per-instance, or for all combo boxes using this control template; this solution uses the latter:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AlpmGray}" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="0" Margin="1" Background="White"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ComboPath}"/>
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
        </Path>
    </Grid>            
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AlpmGray}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AlpmRed}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This binds the **Fill** to the **TemplatedParent** (in this case the ToggleButton), and thus the enabled state of the button (generally tied to the parent control).